# OpenCL function calls

Tags: opencl

I'm working on an `openCL` kernel that loads up some points, decides which is the highest, and returns it. All good there, but I want to add a calculation before the highest evaluation. This compares the point to a pair of lines. I have it written and working to a degree, as follows:

```
    size_t i = group_id * group_stride + local_id;
    while (i < n){
        //load up a pair of points using the index to locate them within a massive dataSet
        int ia = LOAD_GLOBAL_I1(input, i);
        float4 a = LOAD_GLOBAL_F4(dataSet, ia);

        int ib = LOAD_GLOBAL_I1(input, i + group_size);
        float4 b = LOAD_GLOBAL_F4(dataSet, ib);

        //pre-assess the points relative to lines
        if(pass == 0){
            float px = a.x;
            float py = a.y;
            int checkAnswer;
        //want to write this section as a function
            float x1 = tri_input[0].x; float y1 = tri_input[0].y;
            float x2 = tri_input[2].x; float y2 = tri_input[2].y;
            float check = sign((x1-x2) * (py-y1) - (y2-y1) * (px-x1));
            if(check != tri_input[3].x){        //point is outside line 1
                checkAnswer = 1;
            }
            else{
                x1 = tri_input[2].x;  y1 = tri_input[2].y;
                x2 = tri_input[1].x;  y2 = tri_input[1].y;
                check = sign((x1-x2)*(py-y1) - (y2-y1)*(px-x1));
                if(check != tri_input[3].y){    //point is outside line 2
                    checkAnswer = 2;
                }
                else{
                    checkAnswer = 0;            //point is within both lines
        }}}

        //later use the checkAnswer result to change the following
        //find the highest of the pair
        float4 result;
        if(a.z>b.z) result = a;
        else result = b;

        //load up the previous highest result locally
        float4 s = LOAD_LOCAL_F4(shared, local_id);

        //if the previous highest beat this, stick, else twist
        if(s.z>result.z){ STORE_LOCAL_F4(shared, local_id, s);}
        else{ STORE_LOCAL_F4(shared, local_id, result);}
        i += local_stride;
    }
```

What I would like to do is call the line check twice as a function, i.e the code becomes:

```
   size_t i = group_id * group_stride + local_id;
   while (i < n){
        //load up a pair of points using the index to locate them within a massive dataSet
        int ia = LOAD_GLOBAL_I1(input, i);
        float4 a = LOAD_GLOBAL_F4(dataSet, ia);

        int ib = LOAD_GLOBAL_I1(input, i + group_size);
        float4 b = LOAD_GLOBAL_F4(dataSet, ib);

        //pre-assess the points relative to lines
        if(pass == 0){
            float px = a.x;
            float py = a.y;
            int checkA = pointCheck( px,  py, tri_input);
            px = b.x;
            py = b.y;
            int checkB = pointCheck( px,  py, tri_input);
        }

        //later use the checkAnswer result to change the following
        //find the highest of the pair
        float4 result;
        if(a.z>b.z) result = a;
        else result = b;

        //load up the previous highest result locally
        float4 s = LOAD_LOCAL_F4(shared, local_id);

        //if the previous highest beat this, stick, else twist
        if(s.z>result.z){ STORE_LOCAL_F4(shared, local_id, s);}
        else{ STORE_LOCAL_F4(shared, local_id, result);}
        i += local_stride;
    }
```

In this instance the function is:

```
int pointCheck( float *px,  float *py, float2 *testLines){

float x1 = testLines[0].x; float y1 = testLines[0].y;
float x2 = testLines[2].x; float y2 = testLines[2].y;
float check = sign((x1-x2) * (py-y1) - (y2-y1) * (px-x1));
if(check != testLines[3].x){ //point is outside line 1
    return 1;
}
else{
    x1 = testLines[2].x;  y1 = testLines[2].y;
    x2 = testLines[1].x;  y2 = testLines[1].y;
    check = sign((x1-x2)*(py-y1) - (y2-y1)*(px-x1));
    if(check != testLines[3].y){ //point is outside line 2
        return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 0; //point is within both lines
}}}
```

Whilst the longhand version runs fine and returns a normal 'highest point' result, the function version returns an erroneous result (not detecting the highest point I have hidden in the data set). It produces a wrong result even though the function as yet has no overall effect.

What am I doing wrong?

S

[Update]:
This revised function works as far as the commented out line, then hangs on something:

```
int pointCheck(float4 *P, float2 *testLines){

float2 *l0 = &testLines[0];
float2 *l1 = &testLines[1];
float2 *l2 = &testLines[2];
float2 *l3 = &testLines[3];

float x1 = l0->x; float y1 = l0->y;
float x2 = l2->x; float y2 = l2->y;

float pX = P->x; float pY = P->y;
float c1 = l3->x; float c2 = l3->y;

//float check = sign((x1-x2) * (pY-y1) - (y2-y1) * (pX-x1)); //seems to be a problem with sign
//    if(check != c1){            //point is outside line 1
//        return 1;
//    }
//    else{
//        x1 = l2->x; y1 = l2->y;
//        x2 = l1->x; y2 = l1->y;
//        check = sign((x1-x2) * (pY-y1) - (y2-y1) * (pX-x1));
//        if(check != c2){        //point is outside line 2
//            return 2;
//        }
//        else{
//            return 0;           //point is within both lines
//    }}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate issue is how you pass the parameters to the called function:

```
int checkA = pointCheck( px,  py, tri_input);
```

whereas the function itself expects pointers for px and py. You should instead call the function as:

```
int checkA = pointCheck(&px,  &py, tri_input);
```

It is surprising that OpenCL does not give build errors for this kernel.

In my experience, some OpenCL runtimes do not like multiple return statements in a single function. Try to save the return value into a local variable and use a single return statement at the end of the function. This is because OpenCL does not support real function calls, but rather inlines all functions directly into the kernel. A best practice is therefore to mark all non `__kernel` functions as `inline`, and treat them as such (i.e. make it easier for the compiler to inline your function by not using multiple return statements).

Comment: Yip, that does the trick. Wishing I hadn't spent hours getting it wrong now! I think the non-results that I got previously were because the kernel wasn't building/running. But yes, no build errors were returned, which wasn't exactly helpful either! Thanks for the hint

Comment: @sam_mcelhinney, pass `"-I. -Werror"` as an `options` parameter to `clBuildProgram` then it should be reported this and probably other errors if there are more.